# Linq - Group counts with 0 entries are missing from results

Tags: c#, linq

I have some linq which returns a list of properties and the number of bookings for a given year. However if a property has no bookings then it is not included in the resultset.

```
 var bookings = from b in db.Bookings
                      orderby b.PropertyId
                      where b.StartDate.Year == Year
                      group b by b.Property.Title into grp
                      select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count() };
```

How can this be changed to include properties with no bookings?

Comment: Is this Linq2SQL or LINQ2Objects? In the first case the where-clause does not fit, because when no items are within the result of the group how should there where filter any further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there's a Properties table based on your code. You need to select from Properties instead:

```
var bookings = from p in db. Properties
               orderby p.Id
               group p by p.Title into grp
               select new
               {
                   key = grp.Key,
                   cnt = grp.Count(p => p.Bookings.Where(b => b.StartDate.Year == Year))
               };
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should filter on year in the count, then

```
var bookings = from b in db.Bookings
               orderby b.PropertyId
               group b by b.Property.Title into grp
               select new { 
                    key = grp.Key, 
                    cnt = grp.Count(x => x.StartDate.Year == Year) 
               };
```